# Several input parameters in an fzero function in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

```
dT0 = fzero('funzeroproj',1)
```

How do you have more input parameters in an fzero function? I want more inputs than just dT0g. For example, i want TL = pi/2 without having to go in and manually changing it in this function;

```
function f = funzero(dT0g)
    TL = 2*pi/6;
    T0 = -2*pi/6;
    k = 10;
    options = odeset('Events',@yzero);
    [x,vinkel,dphikors,vinkele,ie]=ode45(@ode45projekt,[0 k],[T0, dT0g],options);
    Tslut = vinkele(2,1)

    f = Tslut-TL 
end
```

(which is saved as a separate file named funzeroproj.m)

Answer (score 1):

You can use anonymous handles:

```
% Some function defined with more than one parameter
function out = genericFunction(x,y,z)
     out=x*y+z;
end
```

Then:

```
%Define parameters
Par1 = 1;
Par2 = 2;

%Define function handle
specificFunction = @(t) genericFunction(t,Par1,Par2);

%specificFunction only depends on a single parameter

%Solve equation
dT0 = fzero(genericFunction,1)
```

Note that, when you create the function handle `specificFunction`, its constant parameters are saved. Even if you change `Par1` or `Par2`, `specificFunction` will always return results based on the value they had when it was created. If you modify the values of the parameters, you'll have to execute again line `specificFunction = @(t) ...` before going through the solver.

---

Now, you can even put the handle definition in the same line as the call to the solver:

```
function f = funzero(dT0g,TL,T0,k)
    options = odeset('Events',@yzero);
    [x,vinkel,dphikors,vinkele,ie]=ode45(@ode45projekt,[0 k],[T0, dT0g],options);
    Tslut = vinkele(2,1)

    f = Tslut-TL 
end
```

...

```
TL = 2*pi/6;
T0 = -2*pi/6;
k = 10;
dT0 = fzero(@(x) funzeroproj(x,TL,T0,k),1)
```